# Mango query on LokiJs collection changes size of collection

Tags: node.js, lokijs

I'm using LokiJs as an in-memory cache for an application that stores data in CouchDB and allows retrieval through a NodeJS server. Per the [documentation on constructing queries](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/wiki), the results of my query are assigned to a result set object:

```
let result = combinedCache.find({'left.errorCode': errorCode});
```

This `combinedCache` collection is the result of an `.eqJoin` of two other collections:

```
    var cache = new loki('loki.db');

    errorCodeCache = cache.addCollection('errorCodes');
    messageCache = cache.addCollection('messages');
    errorCodeCache.insert(docs.errorCodes);
    messageCache.insert(docs.messages);
    combinedCache = errorCodeCache.eqJoin(
        messageCache,
        'messageId',
        '_id'
    );
```

This creates two collections, an `errorCodeCache` collection and a `messageCache` collection. The `combinedCache` is the result of the join on the `messageId` of the errorCode docs and the `_id` of the message docs. The size of the resulting `combinedCache` is well over 1000 when I check using `combinedCache.data().length`.

However, after I perform a query against the cache, the size of the original collection is changed to the size of the result; in other words, if my query returns 1 CouchDB document, `combinedCache`'s size is now 1. I couldn't find any reference in the documentation that stated that `.find` queries on a collection mutate the results of the collection itself. If this is the case, how can the size of the collection be preserved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who sees this, I managed to figure it out using this [article](https://medium.com/@tech_fort/an-introduction-to-lokijs-the-idiomatic-way-d24a4c546f7).

```
// branch just long enough to determine count of customers under 30 without filter affecting irishCustomers results
var lt30count = irishCustomers.copy().find({ ‘age’: { ‘$lt’ : 30 }).data().length;
```

So the solution is to add `.copy()` to create a temporary copy of the data if you do not want the filter to modify the collection.